# SQL Server 2016 - temp tables persisting past child procs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temp-tables

I have an **intermittent** issue with temp tables being called from procs. I'm going to attempt to describe the situation.

- I'm running a large SQL string from Java.
- This string calls multiple procs, including the procs I'll call ProcA and ProcB.
- As part of ProcA I create a temp table #roles using a SELECT  INTO #roles. This proc **does not** have a column named cycleid.
- As part of ProcB I also create a temp table #roles using a SELECT  INTO #roles. This proc **does** have a column named cycleid.

For the most part, this works as intended. My understanding of temp tables in this scenario is that they get destroyed as soon as the proc in which they get created is finished running. And since these are both "children" of the main statement, they shouldn't be able to access each other's temp tables.

Occasionally though, I will get the following error:

> :Exception::com.inet.tds.SQLException: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ProcB, Line 123, Sqlstate S0022[QA-SERVER]Invalid column name 'cycleid'

Seems like the Server is reading from or assumes the structure of the wrong temp table (which by now should have been destroyed).

Does anyone have an explanation or maybe a direction I can start to do more research to figure this out? Thanks all.

There is a workaround of renaming all the temp tables to be unique or maybe dropping them, but that's **a lot** of refactoring and testing.

Comment: A [mre] will help us help you. My guess is  that you have a process where ProcA is calling ProcB, and thus ProcB has access the temporary table in ProcA. Of course, the simple solution would be don't reuse object names (even temporary ones) for objects with different definitions.

Comment: I can try to write up some mock code, but the problem is it isn' (easily) reproducible. Most times it works, and occasionally it doesn't. Next time we run it it works again =c(

I'm aware that if I called ProcB from ProcA, it would have access to the temp tables, but in this case they're both being called by a parent SQL statement.

Comment: Which is why I recommend changing the name. Reuse of object names to mean different things is simply bad practice. I wouldn't be surprised if this error is hiding a bigger problem.

Comment: I agree with Larnu.  Simply change the temp table to #rolesA and #rolesB would be sufficient different enough to not hit this.  Alternatively, it may be an execution plan error. 
 Are you doing any dynamic SQL?  You could try OPTION RECOMPILE to force a new execution plan with each run, but the BEST option is unique object names.

Comment: This error would be explainable if the temp table exists before `B` is called (reusing temp tables across scopes is a "by design" feature of T-SQL to enable data sharing). Even though this *should* not be the case in your scenario (assuming your outer statements never create `#roles`), many and subtle are the problems that can arise. If you're going to rewrite anything, also consider table variables -- they have their own issues with cardinality estimation, but at least they have no problems with scoping.

Comment: Since you know that this specific error can occur, you can also capture that specific error in the outer procedure and log it (along with arguments and any other useful information). In addition, perhaps you don't really need to use temp tables at all? See far too much reliance on the abuse of the common <select into #temp, do something trivial to #temp, select from #temp) pattern.